# System.Drawing.Image Doesn't contain definition for 'GetPixel','LockImage'

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on setting up contrast of an image in C#,but i am getting error saying

> "System.Drawing.Image Doesn't contain definition for
>   'GetPixel','LockImage'"

for the following code.

```
 public static Bitmap AdjustContrast(Bitmap OriginalImage, float Value)
        {
            Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height);
            BitmapData NewData =
                Image.LockImage(NewBitmap);

            BitmapData OldData = Image.LockImage(OriginalImage);
            int NewPixelSize = Image.GetPixelSize(NewData);
            int OldPixelSize = Image.GetPixelSize(OldData);
            Value = (100.0f + Value) / 100.0f;
            Value *= Value;

            for (int x = 0; x < NewBitmap.Width; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < NewBitmap.Height; ++y)
                {
                    Color Pixel = Image.GetPixel(OldData, x, y, OldPixelSize);
                    float Red = Pixel.R / 255.0f;
                    float Green = Pixel.G / 255.0f;
                    float Blue = Pixel.B / 255.0f;
                    Red = (((Red - 0.5f) * Value) + 0.5f) * 255.0f;
                    Green = (((Green - 0.5f) * Value) + 0.5f) * 255.0f;
                    Blue = (((Blue - 0.5f) * Value) + 0.5f) * 255.0f;
                    Image.SetPixel(NewData, x, y,
                      Color.FromArgb(MathHelper.Clamp((int)Red, 255, 0),
                        MathHelper.Clamp((int)Green, 255, 0),
                       MathHelper.Clamp((int)Blue, 255, 0)),
                       NewPixelSize);
                }
            }
            Image.UnlockImage(NewBitmap, NewData);
            Image.UnlockImage(OriginalImage, OldData);
            return NewBitmap;
        }
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because the compiler sees Image and attempts to find `GetPixel` and `LockImage` methods in the `System.Drawing.Image` class.  Those methods don't exist in that class and so you get your error.

It looks like you're getting your code from [James Craig's blog](http://www.gutgames.com/), specifically [this page](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Adjusting-Contrast-of-an-Image-in-C.aspx). At the bottom of his snippet he indicates that some of the methods are from his utility library and he specifically names `LockImage`.  If you haven't done so already, download his utility library (there's a link on the page I linked) and I imagine you'll find this method and `GetPixel` too.

When you do use the utility library be sure to specify your namespaces to disambiguate classes found in the utility library and those in the standard Microsoft libraries.

Comment: It seems library has changed. I used SwiftBitmap class in lib